# Merge .CSV-rows based on a column's content - sum another colum

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv, export-csv

I've managed to export some data from several files and create a single .csv using the `Export-Csv` command in PowerShell. My current .csv file looks like this now:

```
CA;ArtNr;Menge;CD;CE;CF;CG;CH
RN;42450;7;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;72250;2;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;42450;3;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;72250;2;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;42450;3;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
```

Now in the last step I want to merge all rows that have the same value in column `CB` and sum up their value of `CC`.
So my desired outcome would be:

```
CA;ArtNr;Menge;CD;CE;CF;CG;CH
RN;42450;13;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;72250;4;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
```

Anyone able to help me (in a PowerShell-newby-freindly way)?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
If I adjust your code into a script to add it as a next step, it just gives me an empty .csv-file.

```
$csv = "X:\folder\file.name.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
$csv | Group-Object ArtNr | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group[0].Menge = ($_.Group.Menge | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    $_.Group[0]
}
$csv | Export-Csv -Path "x:\folder\file.name.new.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: The rest of the columns will always hold the same values? If they don't how should the result object look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it. This will take the first value of each group, however, as in my comment, if the values will not be the same on each item of each group (excluding **CB & CC**) you need to specify how to handle that.

```
$csv = @'
CA;CB;CC;CD;CE;CF;CG;CH
RN;42450;7;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;72250;2;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;42450;3;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;72250;2;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
RN;42450;3;H;10200;some Text;another column;more text
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

$csv | Group-Object CB | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group[0].CC = ($_.Group.CC | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    $_.Group[0]
} | Export-Csv -Path "x:\folder\file.name.new.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Result looks like this:

```
CA CB    CC CD CE    CF        CG             CH
-- --    -- -- --    --        --             --
RN 42450 13 H  10200 some Text another column more text
RN 72250  4 H  10200 some Text another column more text
```

#### Edit:

If you were importing the data from a CSV it would look like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "X:\path\to\file.csv" -Delimiter ';'

$csv | Group-Object CB | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group[0].CC = ($_.Group.CC | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    $_.Group[0]
} | Export-Csv -Path "x:\folder\file.name.new.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Or you can directly pipe the import to the script, like this:

```
Import-Csv "X:\path\to\file.csv" -Delimiter ';' | Group-Object CB |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group[0].CC = ($_.Group.CC | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    $_.Group[0]
} | Export-Csv -Path "x:\folder\file.name.new.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I just added some code to my question in which I am attemting to use it for a file as I will implement it into my script later on. Would you please tell me what I am doing wrong as my result-.csv ist just empty? **Note:** I also added two column names that I am actually using to show that they do not have any symbols.

Comment: @Nerevar.de I edited the code, you can just pipe the result of the foreach loop directly to `Export-Csv`. If you want to save the result first and then export you can do `$result = $csv | Group-Object CB.....` and then `$result | Export-Csv ......`

Comment: 2bh I still get the result of an empty file. Is my way of opening the file correct? As that is the only different part compared to your code (because you have fix example data). **EDIT:** It works if I you the fixed example data aswell. So I guess it's how I open the file.

Comment: @Nerevar.de You have never shown how you're opening the file. Did you check that the variable where you store the result of `Import-Csv` has data?

Comment: It's in my question. First line after the EDIT

Comment: OKay. Now I'm 100% sure that I've been trying to open it the wrong way. 2bh I still don't know what I did wrong upon opening and how it's supposed to be **but** I managed to implement your code into script that is creating the file and it's working as intended. Thank you very much @Santiago Squarzon

Comment: @Nerevar.de check out the last edit on my answer, hope it makes sense :)