# Powershell CSV Import. Adding values together if username match

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, csv-import

I have the following CSV file that I have imported into Powershell array

```
  User     Today  MTD
  ----     -----  ---
  User1    5      15
  User1    3      32
  User2    2      5
  User1    1      23
  User2    3      34
  User3    3      34
```

If the user matches I would like to add the Today and MTD figures to one line

Example: User1 would be "Today" 5+3+1=9 "MTD" 15+32+23=70

Required output:

```
  User     Today  MTD
  ----     -----  ---
  User1    9      70
  User2    5      39
  User3    3      34
```

I can list data for one  username by using

```
$arr.Where({$_.User -eq "user1"})
```

But no idea how to add the today and MTD together

Comment: I am guessing that i need to push the data to another array and match the $_.User and add the data that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go, I answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578806/merge-csv-rows-based-on-a-columns-content-sum-another-colum/67578955#67578955).

#### Code:

```
$csv = @'
User,Today,MTD
User1,5,15
User1,3,32
User2,2,5
User1,1,23
User2,3,34
User3,3,34
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv | Group-Object User | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group[0].Today = ($_.Group.Today | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    $_.Group[0].MTD = ($_.Group.MTD | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    $_.Group[0]
}
```

#### Output:

```
User  Today MTD
----  ----- ---
User1     9  70
User2     5  39
User3     3  34
```

#### Edit

To export the results you can do this:

```
$csv | Group-Object User | ForEach-Object {
    # Original code here...
} | Export-Csv newCsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or this if you want to preserve the new object in memory:

```
$newCsv = $csv | Group-Object User | ForEach-Object {
    # Original code here...
}

$newCsv | Export-Csv newCsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thanks you Santiago - I have spent hours looking for what I needed :)

Comment: @mcgster No problem, glad to help ;) Have a look at [Steven's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662439/15339544) answer too, I think it's far easier to understand the code if you're new to Powershell. It's worth mentioning that here we are modifying the object and in his answer he is creating a new object based of the initial Csv.

Comment: @mcgster check out my last edit, there you have how to export the results

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Santiago's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662296/4749264), Similar solution, but now that it's written I might as well share it...

I setup the test data with custom objects which I'm omitting for brevity.

```
Import-Csv 'c:\temp\TestCsvData.csv' | 
Group-Object -Property User |
ForEach-Object{
    $SumToday = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Today -Sum).Sum
    $SumMTD   = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property MTD -Sum).Sum
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
            User  = $_.Name
            Today = $SumToday
            MTD   = $SumMTD
        }
    } |
Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\NewCsvFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

This outputs fresh objects as opposed to selecting and manipulating the first in a group.  If needed you can add a new `Export-Csv` command after this to get a new CSV file.

**Alternate Approach, Only For Fun:**

```
$Hash = [Ordered]@{}

Import-Csv 'c:\temp\TestCsvData.csv' |
ForEach-Object{
    If( $Hash.Contains( $_.User ) ) {    
        [Int]$Hash[$_.User].Today += $_.Today
        [Int]$Hash[$_.User].MTD   += $_.MTD
    }
    Else {
        $Hash[$_.User] = $_
    }
}

$Hash.Values | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\NewCsvFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

This doesn't use `Group-Object`.  It's definitely harder to read, but mostly because the type casting is needed to ensure you are adding numbers instead of strings.  But, I tried to minimize it by moving the cast all the way left and not casting the right operand, PowerShell's Type conversion engine will take care of that for us.

This is somewhat similar to Santiago's example in that it takes the first object found for a given user and simply updates it's properties as it encounters additional objects with the same user name.  However, unlike the other examples this doesn't purely stream down the pipeline.  As such, it may use more memory, which is only an issue in extreme cases.

Comment: This far more readable and easier to understand for people new to powershell. +1 :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon While technically I can't disagree, I think your code is still quite readable. I'd point out, I suspect yours is more efficient, because you are unrolling the property and sending less data down the pipe.  Only an issue in very big jobs of course...

Comment: Yes, I always opt for the more efficient (in my eyes) and less readable code... I usually tend to avoid pipelines too whenever possible.

Comment: @Steven Thank you Steven, please can you let me know where I put the Export-Csv?

Comment: NP, I edited the answer to include the `Export-Csv` command.